# Why is hadoop slow for a simple hello world job

Tags: hadoop

I am following the tutorial on the hadoop website: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html.
I run the following example in Pseudo-Distributed Mode.

```
time hadoop jar hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.1.2.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

It takes 1:47min to complete. When I turn off the network (wifi), it finishes in approx 50 seconds.

When I run the same command using the Local (Standalone) Mode, it finishes in approx 5 seconds (on a mac).

I understand that in Pseudo-Distributed Mode there is more overhead involved and hence it will take more time, but in this case it takes way more time. The CPU is completely idle during the run.

Do you have any idea what can cause this issue?

Comment: 50 seconds sounds about right.  How much memory do you have?

Comment: I have 16GB on the MacBook and give 784 to the JVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I don't have an explanation for why turning off your network would result in faster times.  You'd have to dig through the Hadoop logs to figure out that problem.

This is typical behavior most people encounter running Hadoop on a single node.  Effectively, you are trying to use Fedex to deliver something to your next door neighbor.  It will always be faster to walk it over because the inherent overhead of operating a distributed system.  When you run local mode, you are only performing the Map-Reduce function.  When you run pseudo-distributed, it will use all the Hadoop servers (NameNode, DataNodes for data; Resource Manager, NodeManagers for compute) and what you are seeing is the latencies involved in that.

When you submit your job, the Resource Manager has to schedule it.  As your cluster is not busy, it will ask for resources from the Node Manager.  The Node Manager will give it a container which will run your Application Master.  Typically, this loop takes about 10 seconds.  Once your AM is running it will ask for resources from the Resource Manager for it's Map and Reduce tasks.  This takes another 10 seconds.  Also when you submit your job there is around a 3 second wait before this job is actually submitted to the Resource Manager.  So far that's 23 seconds and you haven't done any computation yet.

Once the job is running, the most likely cause of waiting is allocating memory.  On smaller systems (> 32GB of memory) the OS might take a while to allocate space.  If you were to run the same thing on what is considered commodity hardware for Hadoop (16+ core, 64+ GB) you would probably see run time closer to 25-30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Is there a way to control those timings? I mean, for dev-mode I would prefer to set those values as little as possible.

Comment: I don't remember the values off hand.  If I get some time, I'll see if I can find them.